# Connect JS with PHP in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to connect js with php, so:
In one step you can add employment and choose that you work from, to now. And when you click on current (now), then div with toDate dissapears. Now I have to do an edit view where if somebody before clicked on current, that field should be active, not toDate div as is now. How can I achieve this?

```
      <div id="toDate" class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">@lang('main.to')</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input type="date" placeholder=" " name="to" value="{{ old('to') }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"><input id="checkbox1" name="current" type="checkbox" value="current"> @lang('main.current')</label>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $("#checkbox1").click(function () {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
              $("#toDate").hide();
          } else {
              $("#toDate").show();
          }
            });
        });        
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. To communicate with a server, we can use a variety of methods, some, better than others.

The most modern method is to use XMLHttpRequests or ActiveXObject (IE only). This is also referred to as "AJAX" (Async. JS & XML). This is the preferred method of causing server-side script execution.

The older method generally uses links to cause a server-side execution of the desired php script but causes a reload of the page which may place unnecessary burden on your server (which is the reasoning behind AJAX)

Your PHP script can then take in data from the link via a "query string" or any other desired representation of the data (provided it has been "url-encoded" in the case of a GET request (see HTTP)) and use it to produce dynamic output.

PHP is an interpreted language meaning that it needs another piece of software to call upon it's awesomeness.

The most popular interpreter is the ZEND Engine, which comes bundled with APACHE.